# How do you remove the first and the last characters from a Multimap's String representation?

Tags: java, syntax, guava

I am trying to output the result of the a `Multimap.get()` to a file. However I get the `[` and `]` characters appear as the first and last character respectively.

I tried to use this program, but it doesn't print any separators between the integers. How can I solve this problem?

```
package main;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Maps;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;

public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    File file = new File("test.txt");
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Multimap<Integer, String> newSortedMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

    try {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            list.add(s.next());
        }
        s.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File cannot be found in root folder");
        ;
    }

    for (String word : list) {
        int key = findKey.convertKey(word);
        newSortedMap.put(key, word);
    }

    // Overwrites old output.txt
    try {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("output.txt", "UTF-8");
        for (Integer key: newSortedMap.keySet()) {
            writer.println(newSortedMap.get(key));
        }
        writer.close(); 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("FileNotFoundException e should not occur");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        System.out.println("UnsupportedEncodingException has occured");
    }
}
```

Comment: You may assign `newSortedMap.get(key).toString()` to a variable, lets say `stringList`. Now call `writer.println(stringList.substring(1,stringList.length()-1));`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have been getting quite a few unexplained downvotes all over stack exchange - I think an explanation should be a necessity but that's a post for Meta

Comment: @HarshPoddar I'm going to try that - put it down as an answer and I will accept if it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may assign `newSortedMap.get(key).toString()` to a variable, lets say `stringList`. Now call `writer.println(stringList.substring(1,stringList.length()-1));`

Understand that when you pass a list into `writer.println` method, it will invoke the `toString()` method of the object and write the output. The `list.toString()` method returns a string with all values separated by `,` and adds `[` and `]` to the beginning and end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

### Just modify the `String` itself using [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)).

> `substring(int, int)`
>
> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins at the specified `beginIndex` and extends to the character at index `endIndex - 1`. Thus the length of the substring is `endIndex-beginIndex`.

So, convert the `Map` into a `String`. Then, `1` is the second character of the `String` representation, and use `mapString.length() - 1` for the rest of it.

Here's some working code:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("output.txt", "UTF-8");
String mapString = newSortedMap.toString();
writer.println(mapString.substring(1, mapString.length() - 1);
```